# Objective c - Is there a way to change a leftBarButtonItem with animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, uinavigationbar, uiviewanimation

In some point in my app, I'm programmatically change the leftBarButtonItem of a viewController (I'm changing the entire button look not just the text).

The result is that the button indeed changes but at once, but I want to do it with some animation (The same way it would do the animation to left navigation bar if I push a viewController)

Is it possible?

Comment: Duncan's answer is correct. It wouldn't hurt to check the docs before posting here. Searching leftBarButtonItem and animate pulls it right up.

Comment: @RyanPoolos: I am curious as to why this has 2 upvotes.

Comment: Either he has 2 friends or its just really not a well known method... I use it every day lol. Oh well question asked, answered, as long as he accepts I guess no harm done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method specifically for that, called setLeftBarButtonItems:animated:

It animates the change in bar button items for you.